# how to archive a chat in telethon api python3?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Is it possible to archive a chat in telethon api using python3
As i searched found in document

```
client.get_dialogs(archived=True)
```

This code snippet is giving details of archived chats.

Answer (score 2):

Archived is a folder with ID 1.

To unarchive you have to set folder ID 0.

Example:

```
client: TelegramClient
client.edit_folder(chat, 1) # 1 is archived 0 unarchived
```